# argsort for a multidimensional ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, numerical-methods

I'm trying to get the indices to sort a multidimensional array by the last axis, e.g.

```
>>> a = np.array([[3,1,2],[8,9,2]])
```

And I'd like indices `i` such that,

```
>>> a[i]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 8, 9]])
```

Based on the documentation of [numpy.argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) I thought it should do this, but I'm getting the error:

```
>>> a[np.argsort(a)]
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

---

Edit: I need to rearrange other arrays of the same shape (e.g. an array `b` such that `a.shape == b.shape`) in the same way... so that

```
>>> b = np.array([[0,5,4],[3,9,1]])
>>> b[i]
array([[5,4,0],
       [9,3,1]])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above answers are now a bit outdated, since new functionality was added in numpy 1.15 to make it simpler; take_along_axis (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) allows you to do:

```
>>> a = np.array([[3,1,2],[8,9,2]])
>>> np.take_along_axis(a, a.argsort(axis=-1), axis=-1)
array([[1 2 3]
       [2 8 9]])
```

Answer (score 14):

Solution:

```
>>> a[np.arange(np.shape(a)[0])[:,np.newaxis], np.argsort(a)]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 8, 9]])
```

---

You got it right, though I wouldn't describe it as cheating the indexing.

Maybe this will help make it clearer:

```
In [544]: i=np.argsort(a,axis=1)

In [545]: i
Out[545]: 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 1]])
```

`i` is the order that we want, for each row.  That is:

```
In [546]: a[0, i[0,:]]
Out[546]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [547]: a[1, i[1,:]]
Out[547]: array([2, 8, 9])
```

To do both indexing steps at once, we have to use a 'column' index for the 1st dimension.

```
In [548]: a[[[0],[1]],i]
Out[548]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 8, 9]])
```

Another array that could be paired with `i` is:

```
In [560]: j=np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1]])

In [561]: j
Out[561]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])

In [562]: a[j,i]
Out[562]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 8, 9]])
```

If `i` identifies the column for each element, then `j` specifies the row for each element.  The `[[0],[1]]` column array works just as well because it can be broadcasted against `i`.

I think of

```
np.array([[0],
          [1]])
```

as 'short hand' for `j`.  Together they define the source row and column of each element of the new array.  They work together, not sequentially.

The full mapping from `a` to the new array is:

```
[a[0,1]  a[0,2]  a[0,0]
 a[1,2]  a[1,0]  a[1,1]]
```

---

```
def foo(a):
    i = np.argsort(a, axis=1)
    return (np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], i)

In [61]: foo(a)
Out[61]: 
(array([[0],
        [1]]), array([[1, 2, 0],
        [2, 0, 1]], dtype=int32))
In [62]: a[foo(a)]
Out[62]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, really helpful explanations!  If you have a sec, could you explain the 'column index[ing] for the 1st dimension'?  That's just converting the array to a (2,1,3) right... why does that facilitate the `i` slicing?

Comment: I expanded my explanation.

Comment: is there a simpler way of doing this? i thought the argsort should have considered what it's going to be used for after sorting the arrays?.....

Comment: Other than hiding details in a function I don't know what kind of simplification you are hoping for.  `argsort` can be used in a variety of ways, not just this context.  Think of it as a building block, which you combine with a few other blocks to do the job.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220729/access-elements-from-matrix-in-numpy is another example of using an index array along with an `arange` array to select elements from rows.  Same logic, only the index array wasn't generated by `argsort`.

Answer (score 4):

I found [the answer here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4724), with someone having the same problem.  They key is just cheating the indexing to work properly...

```
>>> a[np.arange(np.shape(a)[0])[:,np.newaxis], np.argsort(a)]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: oops I guess `np.sort(dists, axis=1)` is what I was looking for 

Comment: @endolith totally.  For my case I specifically needed the indices to sort another array in the same order.  But I agree that the `argsort` documentation could use some more improvement too ;)

Comment: actually I found a way to do it without any sorting at all, just using amin and amax along axes

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`linear indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing), which might be better with performance, like so -

```
M,N = a.shape
out = b.ravel()[a.argsort(1)+(np.arange(M)[:,None]*N)]
```

So, `a.argsort(1)+(np.arange(M)[:,None]*N)` basically are the linear indices that are used to map `b` to get the desired sorted output for `b`. The same linear indices could also be used on `a` for getting the sorted output for `a`.

Sample run -

```
In [23]: a = np.array([[3,1,2],[8,9,2]])

In [24]: b = np.array([[0,5,4],[3,9,1]])

In [25]: M,N = a.shape

In [26]: b.ravel()[a.argsort(1)+(np.arange(M)[:,None]*N)]
Out[26]: 
array([[5, 4, 0],
       [1, 3, 9]])
```

Rumtime tests -

```
In [27]: a = np.random.rand(1000,1000)

In [28]: b = np.random.rand(1000,1000)

In [29]: M,N = a.shape

In [30]: %timeit b[np.arange(np.shape(a)[0])[:,np.newaxis], np.argsort(a)]
10 loops, best of 3: 133 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit b.ravel()[a.argsort(1)+(np.arange(M)[:,None]*N)]
10 loops, best of 3: 96.7 ms per loop
```