# Sort two numpy matrices in parallel, row by row

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, matrix

What is the most efficient way to sort two numpy matrices in parallel, row by row? A toy example:

sort this alpha:

```
a = [['c', 'b', 'e', 'd'], 
     ['a', 'd', 'b', 'e']]
```

then, sort this in parallel to a:

```
b = [['1', '2', '3', '4'], 
     ['2', '1', '4', '3']]
```

Result after sorting:

```
a = [['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
     ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']]

b = [['2', '1', '4', '3'], 
     ['2', '4', '1', '3']]
```

In my real case, `a` and `b` are large, 2D matrices of the same size.

If I use `idx = a.argsort()`, I obtain the indices to sort each row of a. Can these be applied to b in one step? `b = b[idx]` is not working.

Comment: also your example is about 1d list and then you refer to 2d matrices, please give examples that match what you are doing.

Comment: b[idx] does not return an error, but the contents are not sorted. I will update the question toy example.

Comment: Maybe this answer (how to apply argsort to 2D array) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33141247/3981745  - eh, late. Browser hadn't refreshed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`advanced indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
idxx = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None],a.argsort(1)
a_out = a[idxx]
b_out = b[idxx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [75]: a
Out[75]: 
array([['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
       ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [76]: b
Out[76]: 
array([['2', '1', '4', '3'],
       ['2', '4', '1', '3']], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [77]: a_out
Out[77]: 
array([['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
       ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [78]: b_out
Out[78]: 
array([['2', '1', '4', '3'],
       ['2', '4', '1', '3']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Sep 14 2016, 12:36:27) 
    [GCC 4.8.4] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> a = ['c', 'b', 'e', 'd']
    >>> b = [1,    2,   3,   4 ]
    >>> a,b=zip(*sorted(zip(a, b)))
    >>> a
    ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
    >>> b
    (2, 1, 4, 3)
    >>>
```

Comment: This works for my toy example, but in the real one I get the error: 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()