# Sort each column of an numpy.ndarray using the output of numpy.argsort

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I would like to sort numpy 2D arrays according to a previously processed reference array.
My idea was to store the `numpy.argsort` output of my reference array and using it to sort the other ones:

```
In [13]: # my reference array
    ...: ref_arr = np.random.randint(10, 30, 12).reshape(3, 4)
Out[14]:
array([[12, 22, 12, 13],
       [28, 26, 21, 23],
       [24, 14, 16, 25]])

# desired output:
array([[12, 14, 12, 13],
       [24, 22, 16, 23],
       [28, 26, 21, 25]])
```

What I tried:

```
In [15]: # store the sorting matrix
    ...: sm = np.argsort(ref_arr, axis=0)
Out[16]:
array([[0, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 2]])
```

But unfortunately the final step does only work with one dimensional arrays:

```
In [17]: ref_arr[sm]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-48b785178465> in <module>()
----> 1 ref_arr[sm]

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

I found this [Github issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4724) that was created in regard to this problem but, unfortunately, it was solved by mentioning that what I tried works for 1D arrays only.

[In a comment to this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4724#issuecomment-267832934) an example is mentioned that is similar to my problem. The snippet does not solve my problem as it sorts the array by *row* and not by *column*. But it gives a hint in which direction I have to move...

```
a[np.arange(np.shape(a)[0])[:,np.newaxis], np.argsort(a)]
```

Unfortunately I don't understand the example enough to adapt it for my use case. Maybe someone can explain how this advanced indexing works here? That might enable me to solve the problem on my own but ofc I wouldn't mind a turnkey solution as well. ;)

Thank you.

Just in case: I am using Python 3.6.1 and numpy 1.12.1 on OS X.

Comment: So, `a[np.arange(np.shape(a)[0])[:,np.newaxis], np.argsort(a)]` works for you, but you need an explanation on how it works?

Comment: No, it does not work for me as it sorts the array by row. I would like to sort by column. But I hope to be able to find the correct to solution when I understand how that example works.

Comment: Your `argsort` call isn't sorting along the axis you say you want.

Comment: @Divakar: I clarified the question.

Comment: @user2357112: With the argsort alone one cannot sort a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @wedi: No, I mean your `argsort` is sorting along the rows when you say you want the other direction.

Comment: It would be nice to comment when downvoting, so I have a chance to improve my question...

Comment: @user2357112: True! I copied a wrong line! Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33141247/901925 attempts to illustrate and explain the `a[np.arange(np.shape...np.argsort(a)]`

Comment: There's a [numpy issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8708) about making this kind of thing easier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of may 2018 it can done using `np.take_along_axis`

```
np.take_along_axis(ref_arr, sm, axis=0)
Out[25]: 
array([[10, 16, 15, 10],
       [13, 23, 24, 12],
       [28, 26, 28, 28]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically two steps are needed :

1] Get the argsort indices along each col with `axis=0` -

```
sidx = ref_arr.argsort(axis=0)
```

2] Use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to use `sidx` for selecting rows i.e. to index into the first dimension and use another range array to index into the second dimension, so that it would cover `sidx` indices across all the columns -

```
out = ref_arr[sidx, np.arange(sidx.shape[1])]
```

Sample run -

```
In [185]: ref_arr
Out[185]: 
array([[12, 22, 12, 13],
       [28, 26, 21, 23],
       [24, 14, 16, 25]])

In [186]: sidx = ref_arr.argsort(axis=0)

In [187]: sidx
Out[187]: 
array([[0, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 2]])

In [188]: ref_arr[sidx, np.arange(sidx.shape[1])]
Out[188]: 
array([[12, 14, 12, 13],
       [24, 22, 16, 23],
       [28, 26, 21, 25]])
```

Comment: Thank you! I got my solution and looking at it I understood the other example as well. :)