# access elements from matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix A mXn and an array of size m
The array indicates the index of column which has to be index from A. 
So, an example would

```
A = [[ 1,2,3],[1,4,6],[2,9,0]]

indices = [0,2,1]
```

The output I want is

`C = [1,6,9]` (corresponding values from each row of matrix A)

Whats a vectorized way to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
A = np.array([[ 1,2,3],[1,4,6],[2,9,0]])
indices = np.array([0,2,1])

# here use an array [1,2,3] to represent the row positions, and combined with indices as
# column positions, it gives an array at corresponding positions (1, 0), (2, 2), (3, 1)
A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), indices]
# array([1, 6, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = np.array([[ 1,2,3],[1,4,6],[2,9,0]])

indices = [0,2,1]
m=range(0,A.shape[0])
for b in zip(m,indices):
    print A[b]

output:
1
6
9
```