# How to use arguments returned by numpy.argsort() to sort a 3d tensor?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a tensor ,*model* with shape (5,100,200). Its like a (100x200) image with 5 channels. I am trying to achieve the following two things without using for loops:

1. Replacing

I have another image *I* of shape (100,200). I want to replace the smallest pixel value across the channel for every pixel of *model* with the pixel of *I*.Eg:

```
For pixel (3,5)
model(0,3,5)=128
model(1,3,5)=64
model(2,3,5)=256
model(3,3,5)=0
model(4,3,5)=32
```

and

```
I(3,5)=69
```

The smallest value is in 3rd channel so I want to replace *model(3,3,5)*(i.e. 0) with *I(3,5)*(i.e. 69). I use

```
minargs=np.argmin(model,axis=0)
```

to get a matrix of shape (100,200) having channel indices {0,1,2,3,4} of channels having minimum value for each pixel. I just don't know how to use this matrix to achieve the replacement(without for loop).

2. Sorting

I have another model matrix,*kmodel*, of size (5,100,200) and I want to sort pixel values across/through channels of model but by using the values in kmodel as the key. Suppose

```
kmodel(0,3,4)=5
kmodel(1,3,4)=1
kmodel(2,3,4)=3
kmodel(3,3,4)=2
kmodel(4,3,4)=6
```

and

```
model(0,3,4)=9
model(1,3,4)=8
model(2,3,4)=7
model(3,3,4)=6
model(4,3,4)=5
```

So after sorting I should have model as:

```
model(0,3,4)=8 (8 was the value at model(**1**,3,4)and  kmodel has the minimum value ,*1* at channel **1**)
model(1,3,4)=6
model(2,3,4)=7
model(3,3,4)=9
model(4,3,4)=5
```

I use

```
numpy.argsort(kmodel,axis=0)
```

to get the arguments in a tensor (5,100,200) but again I don't know how to use them to achieve the sort(without for loops). 
What is the fastest way of achieving the above goals. I am also frequently using operation of these tensors (5,100,200) like addition and exp. Also providing links to sources containing good tutorials on various ways to specify index of numpy arrays would be appreciated.

Comment: Might be relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044792/

Comment: Thanks. Looking into it. Seems like it would help.