# Numpy - Index last dimension of array with index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to index the last dimension of a 3D matrix with a matrix consisting of indices that I wish to keep.

I have a matrix of thrust values with shape:

`(3, 3, 5)`

I would like to filter the last index according to some criteria so that it is reduced from size 5 to size 1. I have already found the indices in the last dimension that fit my criteria:

```
[[0 0 1]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 4 4]]
```

What I want to achieve: for the first row and first column I want the 0th index of the last dimension. For the first row and third column I want the 1st index of the last dimension. In terms of indices to keep the final matrix will become a `(3, 3)` 2D matrix like this:

```
[[0,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,2,1];
 [1,0,0], [1,1,0], [1,2,1];
 [2,0,1], [2,1,4], [2,2,4]]
```

I'm pretty confident numpy can achieve this, but I'm unable to figure out exactly how. I'd rather not build a construction with nested for loops.

I have already tried:

```
minValidPower = totalPower[:, :, tuple(indexMatrix)]
```

But this results in a `(3, 3, 3, 3)` matrix, so I am not entirely sure how I'm supposed to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `a` as input array and `idx` as the indexing one -

```
np.take_along_axis(a,idx[...,None],axis=-1)[...,0]
```

Alternatively, with open-grids -

```
I,J = np.ogrid[:idx.shape[0],:idx.shape[1]]
out = a[I,J,idx]
```

Comment: `numpy has no attribute 'take_along_axis'`

Comment: @LucEvertzen `np.take_along_axis` was introduced in a recent NumPy version. Update NumPy or use [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47048882/) as the replacement or use  the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can build corresponding index arrays for the first two dimensions. Those would basically be:

```
[0 1 2]
[0 1 2]
[0 1 2]

[0 0 0] 
[1 1 1] 
[2 2 2]
```

You can construct these using the meshgrid function. I stored them as m1, and m2 in the example:

```
vals = np.arange(3*3*5).reshape(3, 3, 5) # test sample
m1, m2 = np.meshgrid(range(3), range(3), indexing='ij')
m3 = np.array([[0, 0, 1], 0, 0, 1], [1, 4, 4]])
sel_vals = vals[m1, m2, m3]
```

The shape of the result matches the shape of the indexing arrays m1, m2 and m3.