# How to use numpy.argsort() as indices in more than 2 dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I know something similar to this question has been asked many times over already, but all answers given to similar questions only seem to work for arrays with 2 dimensions.

My understanding of `np.argsort()` is that `np.sort(array) == array[np.argsort(array)]` should be `True`.
I have found out that this is indeed correct if `np.ndim(array) == 2`, but it gives different results if `np.ndim(array) > 2`.

Example:

```
>>> array = np.array([[[ 0.81774634,  0.62078744],
                       [ 0.43912609,  0.29718462]],
                      [[ 0.1266578 ,  0.82282054],
                       [ 0.98180375,  0.79134389]]])
>>> np.sort(array)
array([[[ 0.62078744,  0.81774634],
        [ 0.29718462,  0.43912609]],

       [[ 0.1266578 ,  0.82282054],
        [ 0.79134389,  0.98180375]]])
>>> array.argsort()
array([[[1, 0],
        [1, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 0]]])
>>> array[array.argsort()]
array([[[[[ 0.1266578 ,  0.82282054],
          [ 0.98180375,  0.79134389]],

         [[ 0.81774634,  0.62078744],
          [ 0.43912609,  0.29718462]]],


        [[[ 0.1266578 ,  0.82282054],
          [ 0.98180375,  0.79134389]],

         [[ 0.81774634,  0.62078744],
          [ 0.43912609,  0.29718462]]]],



       [[[[ 0.81774634,  0.62078744],
          [ 0.43912609,  0.29718462]],

         [[ 0.1266578 ,  0.82282054],
          [ 0.98180375,  0.79134389]]],


        [[[ 0.1266578 ,  0.82282054],
          [ 0.98180375,  0.79134389]],

         [[ 0.81774634,  0.62078744],
          [ 0.43912609,  0.29718462]]]]])
```

So, can anybody explain to me how exactly `np.argsort()` can be used as the indices to obtain the sorted array?
The only way I can come up with is:

```
args = np.argsort(array)
array_sort = np.zeros_like(array)
for i in range(array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(array.shape[1]):
        array_sort[i, j] = array[i, j, args[i, j]]
```

which is extremely tedious and cannot be generalized for any given number of dimensions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a general method:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[[ 0.81774634,  0.62078744],
                   [ 0.43912609,  0.29718462]],
                  [[ 0.1266578 ,  0.82282054],
                   [ 0.98180375,  0.79134389]]])

a = 1 # or 0 or 2

order = array.argsort(axis=a)

idx = np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, array.shape))]
# if you don't need full ND generality: in 3D this can be written
# much more readable as
# m, n, k = array.shape
# idx = np.ogrid[:m, :n, :k]

idx[a] = order

print(np.all(array[idx] == np.sort(array, axis=a)))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Explanation: We must specify for each element of the output array the complete index of the corresponding element of the input array. Thus each index into the input array has the same shape as the output array or must be broadcastable to that shape.

The indices for the axes along which we do not sort/argsort stay in place. We therefore need to pass a broadcastable range(array.shape[i]) for each of those. The easiest way is to use ogrid to create such a range for all dimensions (If we used this directly, the array would come back unchanged.) and then replace the index correspondingg to the sort axis with the output of `argsort`.

*UPDATE March 2019:*

Numpy is becoming more strict in enforcing multi-axis indices being passed as tuples. Currently, `array[idx]` will trigger a deprecation warning. To be future proof use `array[tuple(idx)]` instead. (Thanks @Nathan)

Or use numpy's new (version 1.15.0) convenience function `take_along_axis`:

```
np.take_along_axis(array, order, a)
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't think slices would work in this context!

Comment: @HameerAbbasi They don't. `ogrid` converts them to `arange`s.

Comment: In any case, +1 for making it general.

Comment: After fiddling a little bit, I successfully implemented your solution into my code. +1 for fully answering my question and giving my a very helpful solution.

Comment: You'll want to add `idx = tuple(idx)` now to avoid a `FutureWarning` (and later an error / incorrect result). Something like this is really needed in the `argsort` docs; there should be an easy/standard way to get from the sorted indices to the sorted array.

Comment: @Nathan Done, I'm also partially addressing your last point. Maybe `take/put_along_axis` should be linked from the `arg*` function docs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update and adding `take_along_axis`. I notice the docs for `take_along_axis` (and also `put_along_axis`) do reference `argsort` and `argpartition`, so it seems like these are indeed the standard way this should be done now; it would indeed be great if there was a reference in the other direction from the `argsort`/`argprartition` docs.

Answer (score 3):

@Hameer's answer works, though it might use some simplification and explanation.

`sort` and `argsort` are working on the last axis.  `argsort` returns a 3d array, same shape as the original.  The values are the indices on that last axis.

```
In [17]: np.argsort(arr, axis=2)
Out[17]: 
array([[[1, 0],
        [1, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 0]]], dtype=int32)
In [18]: _.shape
Out[18]: (2, 2, 2)
In [19]: idx=np.argsort(arr, axis=2)
```

To use this we need to construct indices for the other dimensions that broadcast to the same (2,2,2) shape.  `ix_` is a handy tool for this.

Just using `idx` as one of the `ix_` inputs doesn't work:

```
In [20]: np.ix_(range(2),range(2),idx)
....
ValueError: Cross index must be 1 dimensional
```

Instead I use the last range, and then ignore it.  @Hameer instead constructs the 2d `ix_`, and then expands them.

```
In [21]: I,J,K=np.ix_(range(2),range(2),range(2))
In [22]: arr[I,J,idx]
Out[22]: 
array([[[ 0.62078744,  0.81774634],
        [ 0.29718462,  0.43912609]],

       [[ 0.1266578 ,  0.82282054],
        [ 0.79134389,  0.98180375]]])
```

So the indices for the other dimensions work with the `(2,2,2)` idx array:

```
In [24]: I.shape
Out[24]: (2, 1, 1)
In [25]: J.shape
Out[25]: (1, 2, 1)
```

That's the basics for constructing the other indices when you are given multidimensional index for one dimension.

@Paul constructs the same indices with `ogrid`:

```
In [26]: np.ogrid[slice(2),slice(2),slice(2)]  # np.ogrid[:2,:2,:2]
Out[26]: 
[array([[[0]],

        [[1]]]), array([[[0],
         [1]]]), array([[[0, 1]]])]
In [27]: _[0].shape
Out[27]: (2, 1, 1)
```

`ogrid` as a `class` works with slices, while `ix_` requires a list/array/range.

[argsort for a multidimensional ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140674/argsort-for-a-multidimensional-ndarray) (from 2015) works with a 2d array, but the same logic applies (find a range index(s) that broadcasts with the `argsort`).

Comment: This kind of question pops up so frequently, it makes me wonder whether `arg*` functions should perhaps have a flag to make them optionally return all indices needed for getting the non-arg result.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized implementation. It should be N-dimensional and quite a bit faster than what you're doing.

```
import numpy as np


def sort1(array, args):
    array_sort = np.zeros_like(array)
    for i in range(array.shape[0]):
        for j in range(array.shape[1]):
            array_sort[i, j] = array[i, j, args[i, j]]

    return array_sort


def sort2(array, args):
    shape = array.shape
    idx = np.ix_(*tuple(np.arange(l) for l in shape[:-1]))
    idx = tuple(ar[..., None] for ar in idx)
    array_sorted = array[idx + (args,)]

    return array_sorted


if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = np.random.rand(5, 6, 7)
    idx = np.argsort(array)

    result1 = sort1(array, idx)
    result2 = sort2(array, idx)

    print(np.array_equal(result1, result2))
```