# numpy - sort matrix of arrays with another matrix of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix called inference, made of arrays those are storing itemIds. each array represents recommendation for one customer. Here is a snapshot of just one array.

```
inference[0] = array([ 1, 17,  0, 29, 33, 10, 23, 18,  4, 25, 37, 41, 19,  7, 45, 44, 28,
        5, 21, 30, 27,  6, 16, 32,  3, 46, 47, 11, 24, 35, 39, 15, 22, 31,
       43], dtype=int32)
```

I also have a matrix called score, made of arrays those are storing prediction score for corresponding index's itemId. each array represents set of itemId scores for one customer. Here is a snapshot of just one array.

```
score[0] = array([ 4.66423448e-01,  3.04435879e-01,  1.20756114e-01,  7.42338740e-03,
        1.00917931e-02,  3.40771784e-02,  2.95762312e-02,  4.64895252e-03,
       -4.86475747e-02, -5.37142403e-03, -2.96056704e-04, -3.23560827e-05,
       -2.89172482e-02, -3.72408911e-02, -6.24527574e-01, -1.06988378e-04,
       -1.80022987e-03, -3.40648238e-02, -2.07088395e-02, -2.53725616e-03,
       -2.20156523e-02, -3.26039633e-02, -5.12802875e-02, -1.61312032e-03,
       -1.99290374e-01, -1.46841628e-04, -8.44907165e-01, -1.73397407e-01,
       -3.57963537e-02, -1.43663881e-03, -1.67909664e-03, -5.75751424e-03,
       -2.39864983e-02, -3.77825587e-03, -9.72822814e-04])
```

so, for customer 0, model's prediction score for itemId#1 is 4.66423448e-01, score for itemId#17 is 3.04435879e-01... and so on.

I would like to sort that inference matrix by score matrix. for e.g

```
sorted_matrix[0] = array([ 1, 17,  0, 10, 23, 33, 29, 18, 41, 44, 46, 37, 43, 35, 32, 39, 28,
       30, 31, 25, 15, 21, 27, 22, 19,  6,  5, 24,  7,  4, 16, 11,  3, 45,
       47], dtype=int32)
```

At array level, I simply did

```
inference[0][np.argsort(-1 * (score))[0]]
```

and it works. However, when I try to sort whole matrix with

```
new_inference = inference[np.argsort(-score)]
```

it resulted in  nested matrix, where new_inference[0] becomes a 35x35 matrix itself, not array.

What am I doing wrong with np.argsort() here?

Comment: what's the shape of `inferwnce`?  dtype?

Comment: 7 million rows, each row contains 36 items

Comment: You want to sort the 'columns', not the rows?  What shape should `new_inference` supposed to have?

Comment: shape of new_inference would be same as original inference. I want to sort rows - but just within same row. not comparing value of one row to other values in other rows.

Comment: try `inference[:,np.argsort(-score)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seem to want is the `inference` rows reordered according to the sorted rows of `scores`. To sort each row of `scores`, use `np.argsort(scores, axis=1)`. To be able to use that result to reorder `inference`, I will use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33141247/12131013) by [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj).

```py
import numpy as np

def indices_for_2d_sort(a, ascending=True):
    """https://stackoverflow.com/a/33141247/12131013"""
    m = 1 if ascending else -1
    i = np.argsort(m*a, axis=1)
    return (np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], i)

rng = np.random.default_rng()

M = 5
N = 10
inference = np.ones((M, N))*np.arange(N)
[rng.shuffle(row) for row in inference]   # randomizes inference

scores = rng.random((M, N))

new_inference = inference[indices_for_2d_sort(scores)]
```

Comment: changing np.argsort(a, axis=1) to np.argsort(-a, axis=1) brought me exact thing I wnated. thank you!

Comment: I take it that you want the sort in descending order then. I've added an option to the function to change that. Then you won't have to deal with that negative sign yourself.